# Coordinates of the three points and the three angles relative to the x-axis

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

Coordinates of the three points and the three angles relative to the x-axis

[image]

Variables are known only $(x_1,y_1)$; $(x_2,y_2)$; $(x_3,y_3)$; angle $A$; angle $B$; angle $C$

How to find the $(x_4,y_4)$ coordinates?

Comment: Please show your work

Comment: @Narasimham it's on link with blue underline text https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnGmc.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three linear equations to determine two unknowns ($i=1,2,3$, $A_{1,2,3}=A,B,C)$:
$$
\frac{y_4-y_i}{x_4-x_i}=\pm\tan A_i,\tag1
$$
Solve two of them to find four pairs of solution and check which one satisfies the third equation.

PS. In $(1)$ I assumed that the given angles are unsigned and not equal to $\frac\pi2$. If the angles are signed all three pairs of equations have to result in the same solution, so that either the problem is unsolvable or any pair of equations suffice.